# Stripe PHP : how to handle payment success notification

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to handle payment notification after a user pay on Stripe.

**What works :** creating a payment and send user to checkout page

```
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'line_items' => [[
              'price_data' => [
                'currency' => 'eur',
                'product_data' => [
                  'name' => 'Paiement de votre chef Persil & Romarin',
                ],
                'unit_amount' => $commande->getPrix()*100,
              ],
              'quantity' => 1,
            ]],
            'mode' => 'payment',
            'success_url' => $accepted_url,
            'cancel_url' => $canceled_url,
          ]);

        header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
        return $this->redirect($checkout_session->url);
```

I got a nice payment page, everything is OK and i'm redirected well to my "accepted_url" page.

**My question is :**

How am i supposed to retrieve payment information ?
Bonus : how can i send and retrieve metadata like "order id" ?

Thanks for your help if you got the answer, i'm bangin my head against the wall :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}` to your `success_url` which will allow you to fetch the Checkout Session and any other info related to the Checkout Session from the Stripe API.  Stripe has [a guide that covers this in detail](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page).

You can add metadata to the Checkout Session and related objects using [the metadata support in the Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/metadata).